# Dancer request params encoding

Tags: perl, encoding, dancer

Let's say that I have a page which is encoded in 'cp1251' and I submit a form then my params will be in 'cp1251'. But when I access my params in Dancer I get only '?'marks. How can I access the data which is passed?

---

**Update:**

There seems to be a sub called _decode /bellow/ in Request.pm which is called on every parameter. Is there a way to tell Dancer not to call this sub?

```
sub _decode {
    my ($h) = @_; 
    return if not defined $h; 

    if (!ref($h) && !utf8::is_utf8($h)) {
        return decode('UTF-8', $h);
    }   

    if (ref($h) eq 'HASH') {
        while (my ($k, $v) = each(%$h)) {
            $h->{$k} = _decode($v);
        }   
        return $h; 
    }   

    if (ref($h) eq 'ARRAY') {
        return [ map { _decode($_) } @$h ];
    }   

    return $h; 
}
```

---

**Update2:**

I found a way to get the data.
I had to use `request->{_http_body}->{param}` but I shouldn't call `params` before it because it will corrupt it.

---

**Update3:**

To make it work I had to remove the `charset` from the 'config.yaml' and to add

`request->{_params_are_decoded} = 1;` in a before filter.

Comment: Out of curiosity, for what reason are you avoiding UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic encoding only happens when the "charset" setting is set.

Disable it in config.yml and you are done.

Comment: When I do this, the logger crashes.. t => sub { Encode::decode(setting('charset') at Logger/Abstract.pm

Comment: Interesting, could you report that bug on the GitrHub page please: http://github.com/sukria/Dancer/issues